# Trello API | Move card to a new list

Tags: api, trello

I'm trying to move a card from one list to another however, I keep getting this error:

23:32:04.273 - PUT https://api.trello.com/1/cards/CardId/idList?key=Key&token=Token: Trust check failed, The operation completed successfully.

I'm using this from a virtual game server via "HttpService", these are the arguments for a POST requeset(screen capture link): http://gyazo.com/d9c24682c73973473720119c7a5939f8

A request would look something like this: game:GetService("HtttpService"):PostAsync("url", data, HttpContentType (can be left empty))

My question is, Is the Syntax correct for the PUT request, and if so, any idea why I'm getting a "trust check failed" ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the trust check fails: ROBLOX disabled it for normal scripts because it creates a huge security threat to many sites including ROBLOX itself. They only allow their own scripts to run this because of this reason.

Short fix (not easy):
If you have a website, send a get request to a php page that sends put to trello.